# Javascript if else total cart

Tags: javascript

I been trying for past 5 days and still can't figure out.

here's the form

```html
Number of people attending input field<input id="persons" value="1" />

<input type="radio" name="cake1" value="cake1">choose Cake 1 radio button<br>
<input type="radio" name="cake2" value="cake2">choose Cake 2 radio button

<p class="totals" id="subtotal">Total: input field</p>
```

so what i need is if someone puts the number of people attending it will show how much it cost in the total field.

the total price depends on the cake they pick and the amount of people. so 6 people = 25$ for cake #1 but if they put 7 peoples, we will have to charge the price of 12 people = 45$

if they pick cake #2 price will be a different pricing

so hope someone could help me out thanks in advance.

```
Cake #1
Persons     Price
6    ppl =  25.00 $
12   ppl =  45.00 $
24   ppl =  85.00 $
48   ppl =  120.00 $
60   ppl =  140.00 $
80   ppl =  160.00 $

Cake #2
Persons     Price
6    ppl =  30.00 $
12   ppl =  54.00 $
24   ppl =  96.00 $
36   ppl =  135.00 $
48   ppl =  160.00 $
60   ppl =  170.00 $
80   ppl =  200.00 $
100  ppl =  240.00 $
120  ppl =  276.00 $
```

Comment: What's your code so far?

Comment: That seems like really easy logic with arrays.

Comment: Can we see what you've tried so far? 5 days of trial & error you should have quite a bit!

Comment: i have no code that works. :(

Answer (score 0):

Is this the kind on thing you're looking for?

```
// This objects must be ordered by number of persons
cake1 = {6: 25, 12: 45, 24: 85, 48: 120, 60: 140, 80: 160};

var getPrice = function (people, cake) {
    for (var p in cake) {
        if (p>=people) return cake[p];
    }
};

// Example
console.log(getPrice(7, cake1))
```

Comment: Just make sure your `cake` parameter is a variable reference and not a string (if you grab `$("input").val()` it'll be a string unless you add a conversion of sorts).

Comment: oh thank you for the fast reponse. but here's the form in html http://173.203.81.115/share/testform.html. i need to make sure that if they select 8 peoples for example it will = to the price of 12 peoples on the chart on cake #1. same thing if they decide to pick cake #2.     so would it be possible to have the full html and javascript. thank you so much to everyone here

Answer (score 0):

Try somethings lke this

**HTML**

```
<input id="numPeople" value="1" name="numPeople" />

<input type="radio" name="cakeType" value="cake1" />Cake 1<br />
<input type="radio" name="cakeType" value="cake2" />Cake 2

<input type="submit" name="go" id="go" value="Calculate Price" />
<p class="totals" id="subtotal">Total: <span></span></p>
```

**jQuery** (could be JS-only, but most people already have jQuery anyways)

```
// These objects must be ordered by number of persons - {numPpl: price, ...}
cake1 = {6: 25, 12: 45, ... };
cake2 = {6: 30, 12: 54, ... };

// Set the string cake name to the actual array
cakes = {"cake1":cake1, "cake2":cake2};

// fn looks through price arrays, returns price based on number of people
function getPrice(people, cake) {
    for (var p in cakes[cake]) {
        if (p>=people) return cakes[cake][p];
    }
};

$("#go").click(function(){
    var n = $("#numPeople").val(),
        c = $("input[name=cakeType]:checked").val(),
        out = (typeof n == "undefined" || typeof c == "undefined"
               ? "Please select a cake type and enter the number of people attending"
               : "$" + getPrice(n, c) );
    $("#subtotal span").text( out );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/4sv4T/

### UPDATE

To make it update without the submit button, change `$("#go").click` to `$("#numPeople, input[name=cakeType]").change`.

My mistake, the above `getPrice` function tries to compare `p` to `people` as strings - should be as integers. I also now stopped the loop when it has the correct answer. Here's the updated:

```
// fn looks through price arrays, returns price based on number of people
function getPrice(people, cake) {
    var out = "";
    for (var p in cakes[cake]) {
        if (parseInt(p) >= parseInt(people)) {
            out = cakes[cake][p];
            break;
        }
    }
    return out;
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/4sv4T/1/

Comment: tried if I put 7 peoples it gives me 160$ it should give me 45$ also i can't have a calculate button. i would need the total to change live. thank you so much

Comment: My apologies @user2374291, I've updated my answer with the fix to the getPrice function returning the wrong value. As for "change live" - you're on the right track, you need to use `change`. See updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/4sv4T/1/)

Comment: working great thank you so much  Douglas A. Crosby and no need for apology. you saved me days of headache. but one last thing. i would need that if they put the number of persons and it will change the total right away without clicking outside the input field.

Answer (score 0):

- set the same name of cakes, or the user won't be able to change option
- set `type="number"` to persons input field

**HTML**

```
Number of people <input id="persons" type="number" min="1" value="1" /><br/>

<input type="radio" name="cake" id="cake1" value="cake1">choose Cake 1 radio button<br>
<input type="radio" name="cake" id="cake2" value="cake2">choose Cake 2 radio button

<p class="totals" id="subtotal">Total: 0</p>
```

**Javascript** (see [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ruNf/))

```
// store elements into Nodes
var Node = {};
["persons","subtotal","cake1","cake2"].forEach(function(node) {
    Node[node] = document.getElementById(node);
});

function getCake() {
    if(Node.cake1.checked) return Node.cake1;
    if(Node.cake2.checked) return Node.cake2;
}

function computePrice() {
  var cake = getCake();
  if(!cake) return; // no option checked yet

  // fill in the rest of the values to make some effort
  var prices = cake==Node.cake1 ?
    {0:25, 6:45, 12:85, 24:120}:
    {0:30, 6:54, 12:96, 24:135};

  // compute price
  var price = 0;
  for(var i=0; i<=Node.persons.value; ++i) if(prices[i]) price = prices[i];
  Node.subtotal.innerHTML = "Total: "+price;
}

// hook the onchange event for realtime recalculation
[Node.persons,Node.cake1,Node.cake2].forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener("change",computePrice);
});
```

**Note:** since the javascript operates with DOM, it must be placed AFTER the html code or into `window.onload` or [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mozilla_event_reference/DOMContentLoaded) event.

Comment: oh haven't seen this. I just tried and the total doesn't seem to change.

Comment: nvm i see the problem. if I put 6 peoples or less it gives me 0. it should give me 25 and if i put 7 peoples it should give me 45$